# Only one file transferred from html form with multiple option to PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload

Form:

```
   <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file" multiple>
      <input type="hidden" value="GALLUPLOAD" name="DO">
      <input type="submit" value="Upload Gallery Photos">
    </form>
```

Script:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_FILES);
echo "</pre>";
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => 9.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phphhER8w
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 269108
        )

)
```

Files was selected as:

```
"9.jpg" "0.jpg" "1.JPG" "2.jpg" "3.JPG" "4.JPG" "5.jpg" "6.jpg" "7.jpg" "8.JPG"
```

So only first file go into array.

Getting PHP Warning:

> foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given in

```
foreach ($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmpName )
```

Full code, it works for single file upload, but stop working when i add `foreach (`

```
switch ($_POST['DO'])
{
    case "MAINUPLOAD":
        $relp="";
        $maxsize=800;
        $fn='/0.jpg';
        break;
    case "GALLUPLOAD":
        $relp='/gallery';
        $maxsize=1600;
        $fn='/' . time() . '.jpg';
        break;
}


    if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {
        $DirDestination = getcwd() . substr($user['PHOTODIR'], 2);
        echo "<BR> DirDestination ".$DirDestination;

        if (!file_exists($DirDestination))
            mkdir($DirDestination, 0777, true);
        if (!file_exists($DirDestination . '/gallery'))
            mkdir($DirDestination . '/gallery', 0777, true);

        $DirDestination = $DirDestination . $relp;
        echo "<BR> DirDestination ".$DirDestination;

        foreach ($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmpName )
        {
            echo "<BR> XXX";
            if( !empty( $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'error' ][ $key ] ) )
            {
                echo "<BR> err ".$_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'error' ];
//                return false; // return false also immediately perhaps??
            }
            $check=can_upload($tmpName);
            echo "<BR> check ".$check;

                if ($check === true) {
                    echo "<BR> check ".$check;

                    $fileTempName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key];
                    try {
                        $img = new Imagick($fileTempName);
                        $img->stripImage(); //"Removed EXIF data
                        if ($img->getImageWidth() > $img->getImageHeight()) {
                            $newWidth = $maxsize;
                            $newHeight = $maxsize * $img->getImageHeight() / $img->getImageWidth();
                        } else {
                            $newHeight = $maxsize;
                            $newWidth = $maxsize * $img->getImageWidth() / $img->getImageHeight();
                        }
                        $img->resizeImage($newWidth, $newHeight, imagick::FILTER_CATROM, 1);

                        $tile = new \Imagick();
                        $tile->newImage($img->getImageWidth(), $img->getImageHeight(), 'transparent', 'png');
                        $watermarkx = new \Imagick(getcwd() . '/cats/fflogo.png');
                        $watermarkx->resizeImage($newWidth / 2, $newWidth * $watermarkx->getImageHeight() / $watermarkx->getImageWidth() / 2, imagick::FILTER_CATROM, 1);
                        $img->compositeImage($watermarkx, imagick::COMPOSITE_ATOP, $newWidth - $watermarkx->getImageWidth(), $newHeight - $watermarkx->getImageHeight());
                        $img->writeImage($DirDestination .$fn);
                        $img->clear();
                        $img->destroy();
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        echo 'Exception caught: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<strong>$check</strong>";
                }

        }
    }
```

Comment: When you process multiple files the `foreach` loop is a little different to usual. I tend to use something similar to `foreach( $_FILES[ 'inputname' ]['name'] as $i => $void ) {` and then within the loop `$tmp  = $_FILES[ 'inputname']['tmp_name'][$i];` etc

Comment: Do you need `name="file[]"` in the form?